# BackgroundWorker. How do I display the current process by navigating through the TreeView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Scenario_1.
1. The user. Presses the "Start" button;
2. The program. Creates an instance of the user element "ucBackgroundWorker" in "flowLayoutPanel1";
3. The program. Creates a node in the "treeView1";

"Scenario_1" can be repeated an unlimited number of times.

Scenario_2.
There are: 
- Several processes are started in "flowLayoutPanel1";
- in "treeView1" there is a tree of processes;

Scenario:
1. The user. Moves the cursor to "treeView1";
2. The program. In "flowLayoutPanel2" it displays the process (instance
 "ucBackgroundWorker" ") of the node on which the cursor is located;

I tried to implement this scenario (Scenario_1 + Scenario_2) as I understand it.
I thought that the user element instances can be assigned indexes,
and then, depending on the index, display in "flowLayoutPanel2".
For the test, the button of this script made a button "btShowTheProces"
But the project does not work.
When debugging, I get an error.
Form3.cs

```
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add (ucBgWorker [i_ucBWrk]);
```

Error "The object reference does not point to an instance of the object."
ucBgWorker = null;

Your questions
1. How to fix the error?
2. Do I solve my problem correctly?
3. What are the other ways to accomplish this scenario?
For example, that the process was not bound to an index, but to a "string"?
For example, something like this

```
string i_ucBWrk;
i_ucBWrk = "process_1";
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add (ucBgWorker [i_ucBWrk]);
```

**Form3.cs**

namespace rsh
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        // ucBackgroundWorker[] ucBgWorker = null;

```
    int i_ucBWrk=0;
    private ucBackgroundWorker[] ucBgWorker;

    int procNumb;

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // после выбора узла дерева
    void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i_ucBWrk++;

        ucBgWorker[i_ucBWrk] = new ucBackgroundWorker();

        // ucBgWorker[i_ucBWrk].Done += new Action<string, EventArgs>(Worker_Done);
        // ucBgWorker[i_ucBWrk].Cancel += new Action<string, EventArgs>(Worker_Cancel);

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ucBgWorker[i_ucBWrk]);

        ucBgWorker[i_ucBWrk].Run(1);            
        // ucBgWorker.Run(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
    }

    void Worker_Done(string arg, EventArgs evtarg)
    {
        label1.Text = arg + " Done One";
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    void Worker_Cancel(string arg, EventArgs evtarg)
    {
        label1.Text = arg + " Cancel Click";
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }


    //  show the process
    private void btShowTheProces_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        procNumb = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);

        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Clear();
        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(ucBgWorker[procNumb]);
    }
}
```

}

**ucBackgroundWorker.cs**

```
namespace rsh
{
    public partial class ucBackgroundWorker : UserControl
    {
        BackgroundWorker bgWorker = null;
        public event Action<string, EventArgs> Done;
        public event Action<string, EventArgs> Cancel;

        private static bool m_continue = true;

        // Уведомляет один или более ожидающих потоков о том, что произошло событие. Этот класс не наследуется.
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx
        private ManualResetEvent _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        //Semaphore sWaiter = new Semaphore(0, 1);


        public ucBackgroundWorker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

            bgWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            bgWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

            bgWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            bgWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        }

        public void Run(int counter)
        {
            if (!bgWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync(counter);
            }
            _resetEvent.Set();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int input = int.Parse(e.Argument.ToString());

            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lblStatus.Text = "Running";
            });

            for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
            {
                _resetEvent.WaitOne();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i*1); // шаг
                // (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i * 10);
                if ((sender as BackgroundWorker).CancellationPending)
                {
                    this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        lblStatus.Text = "Cancel";
                    });

                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }


        // This event handler deals with the results of the 
        // background operation.
        // Этот обработчик событий имеет дело с результатами
        // фоновая операция.
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown. 
            // Сначала обрабатываем случай, когда было создано исключение.
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                if (Cancel != null)
                    Cancel(this.Name, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Done";
                });

                if (Done != null)
                    Done(this.Name, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            _resetEvent.Reset();
        }

        // This event handler updates the progress bar. 
        // Этот обработчик событий обновляет индикатор выполнения.
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pBar.Refresh();
            pBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }



        // *** *** *** ***
        // *** КНОПКИ  ***
        // *** *** *** ***

        // Cancel
        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bgWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                bgWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }

        // Pause
        private void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (bgWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                if (btnPause.Text.ToUpper() == "PAUSE")
                {
                    btnPause.Text = "Resume";
                    m_continue = false;
                    _resetEvent.Reset();
                }
                else 
                if (btnPause.Text.ToUpper() == "RESUME")
                {

                    btnPause.Text = "Pause";
                    m_continue = true;
                    _resetEvent.Set();

                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

project -  [link](https://ufile.io/xs933)

[image]

Comment: The error "Object reference does not point to an instance of the object" always has the same cause:  you tried to dereference an object variable that contains no object.  To correct the problem, find out why `ucBgWorker` is null.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried to do it, but I can understand why it happens

Comment: You need to provide size to the array: `private ucBackgroundWorker[] ucBgWorker;` to `private ucBackgroundWorker[] ucBgWorker = new ucBackgroundWorker[ somevalue ] ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never initialise the ucBgWorker array.

Change your code to this

```
private ucBackgroundWorker[] ucBgWorker = new ucBackgroundWorker[10];
```

The issue with this is that your array is then set to a maximum of 10.

You'd be better off using a List:

```
private List<ucBackgroundWorker> ucBgWorker = new List<ucBackgroundWorker>();
```

Add items with:

```
ucBgWorker.Add(new ucBackgroundWorker());
```

You can still access items by index:

```
ucBackgroundWorker item = ucBgWorker[0];
```

As long as there are items in the list.

Comment: If you use the list
How do I perform step 3 of "scenario_1"?
How to associate a tree node with a process?
So that the tree was built like this:     
- Process_1          
- - Process_2     
- - - Process_3

Comment: see the drawing of the question. Element "treeView1"

Comment: @koverflow, when you add your Items to the TreeView you set the Tag of the Item to the instance of ucBackgroundWorker you've created then when you select the TreeView item you cast your Item.Tag into a ucBackgroundWorker and display it.

Comment: And it is possible to bind process not to an index, and to "line"?
I have a question number 3 updated. For example, something like this:

`string i_ucBWrk;
i_ucBWrk = "process_1";
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add (ucBgWorker [i_ucBWrk]);`

Comment: Use the `Name` property of ucBackgroundWorker then you'd have to search your `List<ucBackgroundWorker>` using linq. So something like, `ucBackgroundWorker item = ucBgWorker.Where(bg => bg.Name == "process_1").FirstOrDefault();` This will search the list and return only the background worker user controls where the name is process_1.